# MVC 4 Error(how can correct server error in '/' application?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for
>   action 'index' on controller type 'CategoryController' is ambiguous
>   between the following action methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index() on type Onclickmuseum.Controllers.CategoryController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Onclickmuseum.Models.CategoryModel)
>   on type Onclickmuseum.Controllers.CategoryController

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for action 'index' on
>   controller type 'CategoryController' is ambiguous between the
>   following action methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type
>   Onclickmuseum.Controllers.CategoryController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Onclickmuseum.Models.CategoryModel)
>   on type Onclickmuseum.Controllers.CategoryController]
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncActionMethodSelector.FindAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +276
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +181
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, String
>   actionName) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +295
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_17(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +83
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732205/how-can-i-avoid-ambiguousmatchexception-between-two-controller-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that MVC found two action methods with the same name and is confused. You can remove the ambiguity by:

**Adding a HTTP method attribute:**

```
[HttpGet] // This method will be called only on GET http requests
public ActionResult Index() { ... }

[HttpPost] // This method will be called only on POST http requests
public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... }
```

**Specifying an action name:**

```
// This method will be called for /ControllerName/Index requests
public ActionResult Index() { ... }

[ActionName("Index2")] // This method will be called for /ControllerName/Index2 requests
public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting tells that ASP.NET MVC has found two actions with the same name and can't chose which to use.