# how do i call an overloaded action in .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overloading

I have an overloaded action in my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AssignList(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    [AcceptVerbs((HttpVerbs.Get))]
    public ActionResult AssignList(int id, bool altList)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'd like to use the same partial view for both lists but it will potentially have a differently filtered list of Images.

I am trying to call it from another view using RenderAction:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("AssignList", "Image", new { id = Model.PotholeId, altList = true }); %>
```

However I am getting the following error:
The current request for action 'AssignList' on controller type 'ImageController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AssignList(Int32) on type UsiWeb.Controllers.ImageController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AssignList(Int32, Boolean) on type UsiWeb.Controllers.ImageController

How can I call the specific overload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

- combine into a single method like:

  public ActionResult AssignList(int id, bool? altList){}
- Give a name to the overloaded method like:

  public ActionResult AssignList(int id){}

  [ActionName("SomeActionName")]
  public ActionResult AssignList(int id, bool altList){}

I will refer you to this SO link: [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to combine the actions, making `altList` nullable:

```
public ActionResult AssignList(int id, bool? altList)
{
    ...
}
```