# Controller Action Methods with different signatures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get my URLs in **files/id** format. I am guessing I should have two Index methods in my controller, one with a parameter and one with not. But I get this error message in browser below.

Anyway here is my controller methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("Index ");
}

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    File file = fileRepository.GetFile(id);
    if (file == null) return Content("Not Found");
    else return Content(file.FileID.ToString());
}
```

Update: Done with adding a route. Thanks to Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only [overload Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc) if they differ in arguments and in Verb, not just arguments.  In your case you'll want to have one action with a nullable ID parameter like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id){ 
    if( id.HasValue ){
        File file = fileRepository.GetFile(id.Value);
        if (file == null) return Content("Not Found");
            return Content(file.FileID.ToString());

    } else {
        return Content("Index ");
    }
}
```

You should also read Phil Haack's [How a Method Becomes an Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx).

Comment: @R0MANARMY I updated my method but I get 'cannot convert from int? to int' error. I realised same thing happened when I was re-writing Nerd Dinner. Is it something with MVC 2.0? Anyway if I cast to int it still doesn't work inside id.HasValue condition(url not found). Any ideas?

Comment: Nope not working. Url has to be in /files?id=2 format. I wanna do it like here in SO: questions/2576570. Is it about done with routing maybe?

Comment: @Narsil: Hint: what order will routes be evaluated (will the default route be tried before your route or after)?  You can use this tool to help http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 5):

To use the **files/id** URL format, remove the parameterless `Index` overload, and add this custom route first so it's evaluated before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Files",
        "Files/{id}",
        new { controller = "Files", action = "Index" }      
    );
```

See [**ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview**](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-05-cs.aspx) for the basics of mapping URLs to controller methods and ScottGu's excellent [**URL Routing**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) article, which has several examples very close to what you want to do.

Comment: It worked. I did a little reading about routing and all has become clear. Thank you very much. My apologies that I won't mark your answer because R0MANARMY answered my question though it was misguided. Better if it stays that way. Anyway thanks again :)