# overriding Method asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can I override an ActionResult method. Say I have a method Index in AccountController like this

public ActionResult Index()
{

return View();
}

Can I have one more method with same name but with differnt parameters
like
public ActionResult Index(int userid)
{

return View();
}

I dont want to call it like http://something/accounts/index/11
I just want to say http://something/accounts/11

You can look at stackoverflow stuff also
if you go to https://stackoverflow.com/users
i feel users is the controller and the default action is index so dont to call it explicit.
now if you type something like https://stackoverflow.com/users/96346/parminder
the two parameters are 96346 and parminder

I hope it makes sense.

what will be the entries in the global.asax

Regards
Parminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576570)

I think you can do it by hacking some method attributes but I think it would be cleaner if you  write another method then add a route for it.It would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
} 

public ActionResult UserInfo(int id)
{
    //some stuff
    return View(modelObject);
}
```

Then you provide a route for it like:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserInfo", //route name
                "Accounts/{id}",
                new 
                { 
                    controller = "Accounts",
                    action = "UserInfo",
                    id=UrlParameter.Optional 
                });
```

Comment: Hi Narsil,
Thanks for your answer. I tried with this method. but i cant call my method like this http://something/accounts/1
it doesnt work that way. Yes it works if i write http://accounts/userinfo/1

Thanks

Comment: You can call your method directly from accounts/3 if you mapped the route correctly. Can you post your Global.asax?

Comment: Hi Narsil,
I removed the default routing. Here is my global.asax

 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



            routes.MapRoute("UserInfo", //route name
                "Users/{id}/{name}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Users",
                    action = "UserInfo",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    name = UrlParameter.Optional
                });


and here is controller method 

public ActionResult UserInfo(int? id, string name)
        {
            return View();
        }

It works now
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do action overloading (two actions with same name on the same controller with different arguments) but they should be invocable on different HTTP verbs. This is a commonly pattern in ASP.NET MVC applications: one action accessible through GET that renders a view containing a form and a second action that this form will POST to:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] // [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] for ASP.NET MVC 1.0
    public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // TODO: validation passed => do something with the model
        }
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
}
```

There's no need to modify your routes for this, it works with the default ones.

Comment: Thanks Darin,
I know this stuff. but requirment is different. 

regards

Answer (score 0):

You want to over-**load** the method. But you don't need to.

Just make the parameter nullable:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? userid)
{
   return (userid.HasValue) ? ShowUser(userid.Value) : ShowOverview();
}
```

You can take the default route map for this example.

For your (changed) requirements you'll indeed need to modify your routes using constraints.

```
routes.MapRoute("directaccount", "Accounts/{userid}/{someotherparam}",
    new { controller="Accounts", action="ShowAccountByID", someotherparam=null }
    new { userid=@"\d+"});

*here goes the rest*
```

The reg-ex ensures that your other calls won't get eaten by this route. This is untested. I don't recommend to use overloading for this functionality.

Comment: Hi Wikser,
Thanks a lot for your answer. the default index works, but when I have to pass the parameters i have to say like http://something/accounts/index/1
which i dont want to do. 

Regards