# ASP.NET MVC - Overriding an action with differing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that inherits from a base controller.  Both have an edit (post) action which take two arguments:

On Base controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(IdType id, FormCollection form)
```

And in the derived controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SomeViewModel viewModel)
```

If I leave it like this I get an exception because there is an ambiguous call.  However, I can't use `override` on the derived action, because the method signatures don't exactly match.  Is there anything I can do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As addition to Developer Art's answer a workaround would be:

leave the base method as it is and in your derived class implement the base method and annotate it with `[NonAction]`

```
[NonAction]
public override ActionResult Edit(IdType id, FormCollection form)
{
   // do nothing or throw exception
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SomeViewModel viewModel)
{
   // your implementation
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  Seems a little hacky ;) so I leave the question open for a while in case there are other ideas - otherwise it'll do the job.  Thanks.

Comment: The Attribute is `[NonAction]` not `[NoAction]`, Your solution saved my day

Answer (score 1):

I'd chain it:

On Base controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(IdType id, FormCollection form)
```

And in the derived controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(IdType id, FormCollection form)
{
     var newId = //some enum? transform
     var boundModel = UpdateModel(new SomeViewModel(), form);

     return Edit( newId, boundModel );
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SomeViewModel viewModel)
```

I haven't tested this, passing a Post method to another Post should work.  There could be security implications this way.

Answer (score 0):

That's all what you need to do 
On **Base** controller :

adding **virtual** keyword

[image]

On **Derived** controller :

adding **override** keyword

[image]