# Same Name For Action Methods With Different Return Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've two action methods in my controller, both are called on POST request but have different return type:

```
public JsonResult AJAXCreate()

public string AJAXCreateNSave([Bind(Exclude = "Id, OrderItems")]Order order)
```

When I rename the second one to AJAXCreate, it is not called at all. I want to use same name for both action methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloaded methods are not allowed in ASP.NET MVC without an attribute to specify a different action name. Check out this similar question and answer: [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 5):

Much like operations in WCF services, no two actions can have the same name, unless they target different HTTP verbs, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() { }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model) { }
```

If you try and use two actions with the same name, MVC doesn't know which action to select.

Comment: Matthew I have to select 1 answer :(