# How do I use multiple GET methods on the same route in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, get

Suppose I have a resource in ASP.NET like so:

```
/api/cars
```

and I want to expose information about cars for sale. I want to expose it in two ways:

```
/api/cars?model=camry

/api/cars?make=toyota
```

I can implement the search for one of them, but not both at the same time since their signatures are identical. I'm using an ApiController in .NET 4.5: how can I implement both searches on the same resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nullable input parameters.  Since you are using strings, you don't even have to declare them as nullable.  See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906191/mvc-action-with-optional-parameters-which-is-better) article.  The gist is

```
public ActionResult Action(string model, string make)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
    {
        // do something with model
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(make))
    {
        // do something with make
    }
}
```

As described in the linked SO article, any of the following routes will direct you to the right action:

- GET /api/cars
- GET /api/cars?make=toyota
- GET /api/cars?model=camry
- GET /api/cars?make=toyota&model=camry

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc) is another good SO article on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using WebApi (e.g. your `ApiController` is `System.Web.Http.ApiController`)

Then your controller method will simply be

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCars([FromUri] string make, [FromUri] string model) {
    ... code ...
}
```