# Ambuiguity in calling action method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I was creating a sample mvc application and created two action methods (Index) in the Home controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/        
    public string Index()
    {
        return Index1();
    }

    public string Index(string message)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And the index is set as the default action in running the application. On running the application I get the below error,

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.String Index(Int32) on type
>   Mvc4example.Controllers.HomeController System.String
>   Index(System.String) on type Mvc4example.Controllers.HomeController

What I expected is that with out query string it'll invoke the parameterless action method and if there is a query string message is passed then the action method with parameter will get invoked.

Can anyone explain why this behavior?

Comment: It is the way MVC works, the parameters are not taken into account for selecting a method. If you want this sort of behaviour, you need to tweak it yourself, for example using an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` that looks at the query string and method parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the answer in this post: [Routing: The current request for action [...] is ambiguous between the following action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668105/routing-the-current-request-for-action-is-ambiguous-between-the-following) for more details, but to summarize it:

> You can only have a maximum of 2 action methods with the same name on
>   a controller, and in order to do that one must be [HttpPost], and the
>   other must be [HttpGet].
>
> Since both of your methods are GET, you should either rename one of
>   the action methods or move it to a different controller

Answer (score 1):

If you have two methods with same name, Http request attribute must be different

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]        
    public string Index()
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(string message)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That you have a third action like this

```
    public string Index(int id)
    {
            return "int";       
    }
```

would explain this behaviour

of course you don't need the parameterless action either, that's just a special case of the message one, where message is empty

Comment: No I don't have that action method, but I still I get the same error even after adding that action method too which you mentioned.

Comment: you don't need two actions here that are effectively the same, as others have answered already correctly as well, e.g. @Max Brodin