# Attribute routing with string parameters is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am getting the error

> the current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Foo1(System.String) on type
>   Project.Web.Controllers.PageController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Foo2(System.String) on type
>   Project.Web.Controllers.PageController

The a href calling the ActionResults are

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo1", "Page", new { page = "Foo1" })">Foo1</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo2", "Page", new { page = "Foo2" })">Foo2</a>
```

I am basically passing the string instead of a int id ( I realise this is not the best way to do this , but that is not the issue i want to address here )

This allows me to add a string parameter to the Routing for clean urls, so my ActionResult is now

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("{page}")]
public ActionResult Foo1(string page)
{
   ...
}
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("{page}")]
public ActionResult Foo2(string page)
{
   ...
}
```

Why is there ambiguity when the links are being passed to different ActionResults and the parameters are different?

Comment: Try using different route like `[AllowAnonymous, Route("{page/Foo2}")]` for your second ActionResult

Comment: Then i get the error here is an incomplete parameter in this path segment: '{page'. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character - i guess because that is not a correct parameter

Comment: @MilenPavlov. If i add a prefix Route("Foobar/{page}") then is works. I am still not sure why it works though

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668105/routing-the-current-request-for-action-is-ambiguous-between-the-following

Comment: or you can use completely different routes `[AllowAnonymous, Route("Foo1")]
        public ActionResult  Foo1(string page)
        {
            .....
        }

        [AllowAnonymous, Route("Foo2")]
        public ActionResult Foo2(string page)
        {
            .......
        }` and then action `<a href="@Url.Action("Foo1")">Foo1</a>`

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish with this approach? If the `Foo1` action is being accessed, what is the purpose of having `Foo1` passed in as the `page` parameter?

Comment: @JLRishe Foo1 is a dynamic property that can be changed by the administrator. It will not always be foo1. I have a entity type that controls static based pages , the page parameter defines what content to take from the database. Its just experimentation while i am learning asp mvc.

Comment: @gerdi I don't really understand what you are describing. Could you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do instead of using names like "Foo1" and "Foo2"?

Comment: @JLRishe Well Foo1 & Foo2 would just be a page like "about" or "overview" . Static type pages that do not change that often. However the content for the pages come from the database in a entity type of pages. So i want the admin to create the pages him/her self . This connects to one controller. and one entity framework class for all common pages of the site. This allows for one edit / update and delete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the `[Route]` attribute does. Your example is definitely ambiguous.

This:

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("{page}")]
```

means "map this action to any path that has one and only one segment, and treat that segment as the `page` parameter.

So all of these URLs:

```
http://example.com/Foo1
http://example.com/Foo2
http://example.com/SomethingElse
```

would be mapped to the action that has that attribute.

If you have two actions with that same route, then the MVC framework doesn't know which action to map the URL to. Both of them are valid candidates.

I think there is a simpler way to implement what you are trying to do.

In RouteConfig.cs, add a route map that doesn't include the controller name in the URL pattern:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Pages",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Add an `action` parameter to your actions:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Foo1(string action)
{
   // action has the value Foo1
   ...
}

and
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Foo2(string action)
{
   // action has the value Foo2
   ...
}
```

Remove the `page` stuff from your links:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo1", "Page")">Foo1</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Foo2", "Page")">Foo2</a>
```

And you should be all set.

---

**Edit**: If you just want to allow passing in a dynamic value for `page`, then you can get rid of the `Foo1` and `Foo2` actions, and just have one action:

```
[Route("{page=index}")]
public ActionResult Page(string page)
{
    // page is the value specified in the url
}
```

For links within the site, just use ordinary `<a>` elements:

```
<a href="/Foo1">To Foo1</a>
<a href="/Foo2">To Foo2</a>
```

and I think that should do it.