# AngularJS with WebAPI, WebAPI Get method getting skipped

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two applications, one is a WebAPI application that just serves data. The other is an AngularJS application that gets that data. I'm having a problem with my WebAPI `GET` method.

I'm trying to use URL parameters to call the correct `GET` method. From what I understand is that AngularJS will create the URl query for me, and the WebAPI will look for the correct `GET` method with the correct parameters.

What I'm having trouble with is that my correct `GET` method is getting skipped by the WebAPI because it doesn't think that the parameters in the URL query match up to the request. It essentially removes/ignores the parameters in the `GET` method, but I already have a blank `GET` method. So I'm getting a `Multiple actions were found that match the request:` error.

This is how my WebAPI looks. Note that the second `GET` method needs an `SearchParameters` object which just has two fields. `SearchVariable` which is what to search for, and `SearchTerm` which is what field(column) to search for the variable in.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Products
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
        return productRepository.Retrieve();
    }

    // GET: api/Products
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get(SearchParameters search)
    {
        var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
        var products = productRepository.Retrieve();
        if(search.SearchField == null)
        {
            return products;
        }
        IEnumerable<Product> result = null;
        // Search on a certain field for the search variable
        switch(search.SearchType)
        {
            case "Product Code":
                result =  products.Where(p => p.ProductCode.ToUpper().Contains(search.SearchField.ToUpper()));
                break;
            case "Product Name":
                result =  products.Where(p => p.ProductName.ToUpper().Contains(search.SearchField.ToUpper()));
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my `Controller` where I'm calling the WebAPI.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement")

    var ProductListCtrl = function($scope, productResource) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.searchCriteria = {
            searchVariable: null,
            searchTerm: "Product Name"
        };
        productResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.products = data;
        });

        $("#searchBtn").click(function () {
            productResource.query({ search: vm.searchCriteria }, function (data) 
{
                vm.products = data;
            });
        });
        $("#searchCategories li").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selText = $(this).text();
            vm.searchCriteria.searchTerm = selText;
            $scope.$apply();
        });

    }
    app.controller("ProductListCtrl", ["$scope", "productResource", ProductListCtrl]);
}());
```

I set my `searchCriteria` object from a search box on the UI. This is how the UI looks like.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary"
 ng-controller="ProductListCtrl as vm">
<div class="panel-heading"
     style="font-size:large">
    <div class="span5" style="display: inline;">
        Product List
    </div>
    <div class="span2 pull-right" style="display: inline;">

        <label id="searchTerm" for="searchItem" style="font-size: large; font-weight: normal;">
            {{ vm.searchCriteria.searchTerm }} 
        </label>

        <input id="searchItem" type="search" style="color: #337ab7;" ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.searchVariable"/>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <button id="searchBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            <button id="searchCategoryBtn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" >
                <i class="caret"></i>
            </button>
            <ul id="searchCategories" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Product Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product Name</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Product</b></td>
                <td><b>Code</b></td>
                <td><B>Available</b></td>
                <td><B>Price</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
                <td>{{ product.productName}}</td>
                <td>{{ product.productCode }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.releaseDate | date }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.price | currency }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Why is it that my WebAPI is skipping over my second `GET` method when the search parameter is clearly getting put on the URL in my `Controller`? The problem isn't about defining duplicate methods with the same name but different parameters. It's about the WebAPI skipping over the second `GET` method because it doesn't recognize the `search` parameter when looking to see if the `search` parameter in the URL matches with a `search` parameter in the methods.

The moment I change `public IEnumerable<Product> Get(String search)` to `public IEnumerable<Product> Get(SearchParameters search)`, the error appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548254/asp-net-c-same-name-method-that-takes-different-argument-type?noredirect=1&lq=1 [ASP.net c#, Same name method that takes different argument type [duplicate]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.net c#, Same name method that takes different argument type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548254/asp-net-c-same-name-method-that-takes-different-argument-type)

Comment: Just make one method `IEnumerable<Product> Get(SearchParameters search = null)` and handle the null condition inside