# Have Microsoft changed how ASP.NET MVC deals with duplicate action method names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I might be missing something here, but in ASP.NET MVC 4, I can't get the following to work.

Given the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string order1, string order2)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it's view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("order1")<br />
    @Html.TextBox("order2")
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

When start the app, all I get is this:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type
>   ViewData.Controllers.HomeController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(System.String, System.String) on type
>   ViewData.Controllers.HomeController

Now, in ASP.NET MVC 3 the above works fine, I just tried it, so what's changed in ASP.NET MVC 4 to break this?

OK there could be a chance that I'm doing something silly here, and not noticing it.

EDIT:

I notice that in the MVC 4 app, the Global.asax.cs file did not contain this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

which the MVC 3 app does, by default. So I added the above to the MVC 4 app but it fails with the same error. Note that the MVC 3 app does work fine with the above route. I'm passing the "order" data via the Request.Form.

EDIT:
In the file `RouteConfig.cs` I can see `RegisterRoutes` is executed, with the following default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I still get the original error, regards ambiguity between which `Index()` method to call.

Comment: Did you change the default routing?  If your default routing has two optional parameters then it won't be able to tell the difference between the two.

Comment: If you want to overload the action name, you need to use `ActionName` attribute. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @RayCheng - he's not overloading the action name in that way, he's using normal HttpPost method.

Comment: Jason, You don't add that method to Global.asax, there is now a file in App_Start called RouteConfig.cs, and that method is called from global.asax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because MVC4 ships with ASP.Net Web.API you can potentially reference two `HttpPostAttribute` (the same applies to the other attributes like `HttpGet`, etc.):

- [`System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) **is used by ASP.Net MVC** so you need to use it on actions inside `Controller` derived controllers
- [`System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httppostattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) **is used by  ASP.Net Web.API** so you need to use it on actions inside
  `ApiController` derived controllers

You have acidentally referenced `System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute` in your code. Change it to use the right attribute and it should work correctly:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string order1, string order2)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```