# How to call ActionLink when multiple Actions are available

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Controller named Home with two actions:

```
    public ActionResult News(string date)
    public ActionResult News()
```

How can I call one or the other of the two Actions in an ActionLink?
I have tried:

```
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "News", "Home", routeValues: new {date = "12/25/2013"}, htmlAttributes: null)  <li>
```

and

```
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "News", "Home")  <li>
```

In both cases I get

> The current request for action 'News' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous...

Answer (score 0):

I added

> ```
>     [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
> ```
>
> to the News(string date) Action:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public ActionResult News(string date)
```

Now, this ActionLink

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "News", "Home")  <li>
```

calls the News(string date) Action with a null parameter.

An answer to this question gave me some hints... [Have Microsoft changed how ASP.NET MVC deals with duplicate action method names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884048/have-microsoft-changed-how-asp-net-mvc-deals-with-duplicate-action-method-names?rq=1)