# Ambiguous request mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i wonder why ASP.NET MVC 3 is throwing me an exception

The current request for action 'PreviewProfile' on controller type 'EditController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PreviewProfile() on type OSKus.Controllers.EditController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PreviewProfile(Int32) on type OSKus.Controllers.EditController

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PreviewProfile()
{
    return View("PreviewProfile", user.GetPerson(User.Identity.Name));
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PreviewProfile(int personId)
{
    if (personId == -1)
        return View("PreviewProfile", user.GetPerson(User.Identity.Name));
    return View("PreviewProfile", user.GetPerson(personId));
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of this questions:

[Overload MVC Controller Methods][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two [HttpGet] actions with the same name even with different signatures.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PreviewProfile(int? personId)
{
    if (personId.HasValue)
        return View("PreviewProfile", user.GetPerson(personId));

    return View("PreviewProfile", user.GetPerson(User.Identity.Name));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it can't distinguish between them in the routes defined.

But why not change the signature to:

```
public ActionResult PreviewProfile(int? personId)
{
    ìf(personId.HasValue)
    {
        // id supplied, do stuff and return view
    }

    // No id supplied
    // return default view
}
```