# Fill a form with ASP.NET MVC Querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to fill a form with Id and i have made the url in this way

> local-host:1613/Patient/Index/1

Where as 1 is the Id. And i want to fill my form with the data of patient with Id 1. 
But this below function is not being called in Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    Patient p = new CEntities().Patients.Find(id);


    return View(p);
}
```

instead, i am getting into

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}
```

I am newbie in ASP.NET MVC, i have no idea in filling a form with any other way, i found a way but it shows my whole object in query string which is insecure. And this above solution is not working.

Please suggest me good solution.

Comment: Decorate the `Index(int id)` action with `HttpGet`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot truly overload action methods in ASP.NET-MVC so there can be only one `Index` action method(without any additional annotations). Of course you can define few methods with the same name but then you might want to add  `[HttpPost]`(or other HTTP method) annotation above the action method to use it for instance after submitting a form.

Making parameter optional might be helpful:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id){
        if(id.HasValue()){
            Patient p = new CEntities().Patients.Find(id);
            return View(p);
         }
   return View();
        }
```

Please take a look: [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Another advice: try to use scaffolding and see how template does it for you:

1.Right click on a controller folder

2.Add->New Controller

3.Controller with Entity Framework read/write actions(as far as I remember 3rd from the top)

4.Select model class.

5.Select db context(class which maintains connection with database).

6.Ok.

It will generate controller with views, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
local-host:1613/Patient/Index/1
```

This path should be hitting your action method of:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
```

Please check your RouteConfig.cs file and make sure you have the default route set up correctly:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Try commenting out your other Index action method "//public ActionResult Index()", and see what happens when trying to go to local-host:1613/Patient/Index/1