# Get JSON value using grep, sed, or awk

Tags: regex, grep

I have a JSON configuration file I'm trying to extract values from via the following grep command:

```
grep -oP '"private_key": "\K[^\"]*' config.json
```

As you can see, I have working regex, however the \K syntax is not supported in older versions of Regex. For example, if you switch the flavor to Python or ECMAscript, the regex no longer works. I'm wondering if there's some other syntax to achieve the same result.

https://regex101.com/r/jfGwNT/1

Also, if anyone can think of a better name for this question, please let me know!

Comment: Will you consider other tools like sed/awk?

Comment: (I think your title is fine)

Comment: I would use sed or awk, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `gnu-grep`, you can use `sed` like this:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^ *"private_key": "([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file.json

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMyKey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: This is awesome, but how would I remove the comma from the end? I just want what is between the double quotes.

Comment: Yes that can be done. See my edited answer.