# Two Actions in Controler with Different Parameter Settings Conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, overloading, actionmethod

I have two methods (Actions) with different option formats but when I run it I'm told they are ambiguous. Methods shown below.

```
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(){...}
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(string message){...}
```

Comment: you can find you answer here .. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You cannot have more than one action method with same name (& same http verb).

If you want both to work for Http GET requests, you may keep the second one, and check the value of your `message` parameter and based on that return the relevant response.

```
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(string message)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
  {
    // to do :Return something
  }
  // to do :Return something
}
```

This will work for `yourSite/yourController/SelectInstitutionToEdit` and `yourSite/yourController/SelectInstitutionToEdit?message=hello`

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your signatures:

```
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(){...}
```

public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEditWithString(string message){...}

Answer (score 1):

Although the compiler will run this code without any error because of *method overloading* but the MVC framework doesn't allow it. But you can use [`ActionName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute:

```
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(){...}

[ActionName("SelectInstitutionToEditWithParams")]
public ActionResult SelectInstitutionToEdit(string message){...}
```

Then you should call it with it's new name. Like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectInstitutionToEditWithParams", "yourController"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[ActionName("SomeOtherName")]` for the overloaded Action method if its the same get/post call.